# "x not in y" vs. "not x in y"

Tags: python

My question is fairly simple, and surprisingly, I have not been able to find an answer to it:

Is there any scenario under which `x not in y` and `not x in y` yield different results?

What about the case where `x` and/or `y` are more complicated expressions of some sort?

Could operator-precedence cause each of the above expressions to yield a different result?

Comment: **No**. The second one is actually [converted](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ed8b0ee1c531/Python/peephole.c#l407) to the first expression by the peephole optimizer.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I've slightly updated the question, can you please have a second look?

Comment: @barakmanos That's the case for any `x` and `y` regardless of their type.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I'm not talking about types. Will there be a problem if I use, for example, `a or b not in c` vs. `not a or b in c`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: In addition, this is not a question about which one is more Pythonic. It's a question about whether or not an actual scenario exists, under which the above two will yield different results.

Comment: @barakmanos In this case there might be differences, I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @barakmanos Counterexample: `True or False not in [True,False]` and `not True or False not in [True, False]`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: There's an extra `not` in your second expression. If that's a typo, then - nice catch, and I would give you the V for it (though as you can see it is currently not possible).

Comment: @barakmanos Sorry.. Didn't note that. But here's another one: `False or True not in [True,False]` VS `not False or True in [True, False]`

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Like I said, get another couple of users to reopen this question (if you really think that it's eligible to be reopened), and I'll give you the Accept :)